# Find dependent events so that the probability of their intersection is the same as the single probabilities multiplied

Tags: probability

The task is to find three events so that

$$P(A_1 \cap A_2 \cap A_3)=P(A_1)P(A_2)P(A_3)$$

In the case of two events this identity would hold if they were independent. I really have no clue how to find three events that are NOT independent so that the above formula holds. Any examples would be appreciated!

Comment: [Quick beginner guide for asking a well-received question](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/35391/quick-beginner-guide-for-asking-a-well-received-question)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As is usual for first instincts for constructing such a scenario, let us work with the uniform distribution over $\{1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8\}$.  We do this because $\frac{1}{2}\times \frac{1}{2}\times \frac{1}{2}=\frac{1}{8}$, and so if we were to have three non-trivial events this would be a convenient sample space since having a probability of $\frac{1}{8}$ is simple to achieve.  That would just be an event corresponding to a single outcome.

Let's have that single outcome be $\{1\}$.  So, we want three events whose intersection is just $\{1\}$ and who are not otherwise independent.  That would mean pairwise having an intersection of size different than $2$.

$$A = \{1,2,3,4\}\\B = \{1,3,4,5\}\\ C=\{1,6,7,8\}$$

Indeed, we have $\Pr(A\cap B\cap C) = \frac{1}{8} = \Pr(A)\times\Pr(B)\times\Pr(C)$ despite here having $\Pr(A\cap B) = \frac{3}{8}\neq \Pr(A)\times \Pr(B)$ as well as having $\Pr(A\cap C)=\frac{1}{8}\neq \Pr(A)\times\Pr(C)$ and similarly for $\Pr(B\cap C)$ so none of $A,B,C$ are pairwise independent.

Comment: It was a duplicate.

Answer (score 1):

One can try to get a cheeky answer by taking $X_i \sim \text{Ber}(1/2)$ Bernoulli random variables for $i \in \{1,2,3\}$. Then take for example $A_3 = \{X_3 = 4\}$ (just something with zero chance), then both sides are equal to $0$. Note however that one can come up with more advanced examples where both sides are not either $1$ or $0$.

Comment: An event of probability $0$ is independent of _all_ other events (including itself). So, the (unspecified) $A_1$ and $A_2$ both are independent of your $A_3$, and it is not quite appropriate to claim that $A_1, A_2$ and $A_3$ are dependent events (even if $A_1$ and $A_2$ are dependent).

Comment: Fair point, that is correct!

Comment: So how about coming up with an example that does not require pulling the wool over the eyes of the reader?

Comment: It was a duplicate.

Answer (score 1):

I am assuming you want three events that are not completely independent. We know that if $P(A_1\cap A_2\cap...\cap A_{n-1})>0 $, then we have:

$$P(A_1 \cap A_2 \cap ... \cap A_n)=P(A_1)P(A_2|A_1)P(A_3|A_1\cap A_2)...P(A_n|A_1\cap A_2\cap...\cap A_{n-1})$$
This is a direct consequence of the more common $P(A_1\cap A_2)=P(A_1)P(A_2|A_1)$ and can be easily proved by induction.

So in our case, if we assume $P(A_1\cap A_2)>0$ (so $A_1\cap A_2\neq\emptyset$ ), then

$$P(A_1 \cap A_2 \cap A_3)=P(A_1)P(A_2|A_1)P(A_3|A_1\cap A_2)$$

and you want this to be equal to $P(A_1)P(A_2)P(A_3)$, so

$$P(A_1)P(A_2)P(A_3)=P(A_1)P(A_2|A_1)P(A_3|A_1\cap A_2)$$

From our assumption $A_1\neq\emptyset$, so $P(A_1)\neq0$ and we can cancel it:

$$P(A_2)P(A_3)=P(A_2|A_1)P(A_3|A_1\cap A_2)$$

If we consider the case where $P(A_2)=P(A_2|A_1)$, then $P(A_3)=P(A_3|A_1\cap A_2)$ and this can't be a solution to our problem.

Another case is when $P(A_2)=P(A_3|A_1\cap A_2)$ and $P(A_3)=P(A_2|A_1)$. Though I'm not sure if such events do exist, this would be a solution to your problem if $P(A_2)\neq P(A_3)$.

I don't know if you got here too, but this could may help you find the three events.

Comment: It was a duplicate.

Comment: @AnneBauval and why are you telling me?

Comment: I am telling the three answerers. Usually in such a case, answerers delete their answer.

Comment: @AnneBauval is there a reason for you trying to close every answered question? Isn't it useful to have more answers for users with the same problem?

Comment: I am not doing it systematically (moderators like @BillDubuque are more tireless), and it is not "my tryring to". It is the usual procedure on this site: https://math.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/close-questions More answers are useless when they are too similar. They just overload the site.